# I have a small issue with JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, class

I have to create a menu tree from a JSON.

The JSON looks like this:

```
[  
    {  
       "For Home Products":[  
          "Menu Free Antivirus",
          "Menu Premium",
          "Menu Internet Security"
       ]
    },
    {  
       "For Business Products":[  
          {  
             "Client/Servers":[  
                "Menu Professional Security",
                "Menu Server Security",
                "Menu Business Security Suite",
                "Menu Endpoint Security"
             ]
          },
          {  
             "Integration":[  
                "Anti-Malware",
                "Antispam SDK (SPACE)",
                "Rebranding &amp; Bundling",
                "Integration Services"
             ]
          },
          "Small Business",
          "Managed Services",
          {  
             "Gateways":[  
                "Menu MailGate",
                "Menu MailGate Suite",
                "Menu AntiVir Exchange",
                "Menu WebGate",
                "Menu WebGate Suite",
                "Menu GateWay Bundle",
                "Menu SharePoint"
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
 ]
```

The way I tried to solve the problem looks like this:

```
function setData(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data, function(key1, value1) {

        $.each(value1, function(key2, value2) {
            var x = document.createElement("ul");
            x.setAttribute("id", key2);
            document.body.appendChild(x);
            $.each(value2, function(key3, value3) {
                // console.log(value3);
                var z = document.createElement("li");
                z.setAttribute("id", value3);
                document.getElementById(key2).appendChild(z);
                console.log(value3);


            })
        })
    })
    return setData;
}

setData(data);
```

Now, my problem is that the classes are not added correctly. e.g:

```
 <li id="[object Object]"></li>
```

I know that the error is because I'm trying to make a class from an object, but I'm trying to solve this problem for two hours now and I can't find the correct way of doing this without hard coding it.

### Output

[image]

### Code Snippet (Run)

```js
var data = [  
    {  
       "For Home Products":[  
          "Menu Free Antivirus",
          "Menu Premium",
          "Menu Internet Security"
       ]
    },
    {  
       "For Business Products":[  
          {  
             "Client/Servers":[  
                "Menu Professional Security",
                "Menu Server Security",
                "Menu Business Security Suite",
                "Menu Endpoint Security"
             ]
          },
          {  
             "Integration":[  
                "Anti-Malware",
                "Antispam SDK (SPACE)",
                "Rebranding &amp; Bundling",
                "Integration Services"
             ]
          },
          "Small Business",
          "Managed Services",
          {  
             "Gateways":[  
                "Menu MailGate",
                "Menu MailGate Suite",
                "Menu AntiVir Exchange",
                "Menu WebGate",
                "Menu WebGate Suite",
                "Menu GateWay Bundle",
                "Menu SharePoint"
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
 ]
function setData(data) {
    //console.log(data);
    $.each(data, function(key1, value1) {

        $.each(value1, function(key2, value2) {
            var x = document.createElement("ul");
            x.setAttribute("id", key2);
            document.body.appendChild(x);
            $.each(value2, function(key3, value3) {
                // console.log(value3);
                var z = document.createElement("li");
                z.setAttribute("id", value3);
                z.innerHTML = value3;
                document.getElementById(key2).appendChild(z);
                console.log(value3);


            })
        })
    })
    return setData;
}

setData(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It would help tremendously if you gave your variables and parameters more meaningful names.

Comment: @Sphinx if you want to show me that those are objects, I have already noticed and stated that. That's my whole problem. :)

Comment: could you describe what you actually want the output to look like?

Comment: We can try to help you with your question but also note that if you're trying to use this to populate id attributes in html it's bad practice and you should restructure the json. The reason I say this is because you can't have `id="Menu Professional Security"` neither HTML4 or HTML5 allow for spaces in IDs.

Comment: The data structure is not uniform so I don't see how `setData` can traverse it w/out some type checking or explicit key-name referencing so you know what that structure is. Are you using the browsers' developer tools? what kind of errors on the console, etc.?

Comment: @David784 I have just now noticed that the output is different from the one I thought it will be, so this changed the whole problem. The output should be a menu-tree like this: https://gyazo.com/7ba91ab86855639f8b456218e700b947

Comment: I'd be interested to see the output of "console.log(value3);" as a jquery object, but unfortunately you're using plain JS.

Comment: @RyanGibbs it returns as you would think. Mixed objects and what have you.

Comment: I edited and added a running code snippet with an edit. It is easy to see his issues, but Cristian, you need to define the output you need otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: I have just noticed that the problem it's not the way i thought and I don't know if this good or bad for me. The output, should be like this: https://gyazo.com/7ba91ab86855639f8b456218e700b947

this I think, means I have to hard code kinda, everything?

Comment: Problems don't just change unless you change something

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I know, I've now noticed that I thought I must make the menu-tree in a way, and I have to do it completely different. Sorry all of you for this

Comment: an additional point to @pj100 comment; spaces are not valid in javascript names per se, but you can get away with it if you reference using array notation.  i.e. `someOjbect["For Home Products"]`, not `someObject."For Home Products"`

Comment: @RyanGibbs i think someone downvoted because I have made a big mistake and noticed that I was completely wrong from the start and the output should be different. I swear it wasn't me the one who downvoted. 

P.S Thank you for your help. It will surely help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON doesn't match the desired output. I've modified the JSON here to match better with your desired output.

Also, the reason why you were getting `[Object object]` showing up in your code is that you weren't checking to see the type of the `value`s in your `each` loops. Both an array [] and an object {} will show up as `typeof value==='object'`. You could also look for `typeof value==='string'`, but in your given example it's really sort of an either/or problem. So not really necessary to do both checks.

recursion might be a better solution to this. Here's an example:

```js
function setData(data, el) {
 if(!el.is('ul')) el = $('<ul/>').appendTo(el);
 $.each(data, function(key, value) {
  if(typeof value==='object') {
   if(typeof key==='string') 
    el = $('<li/>').appendTo(el).text(key);
   setData(value, el);
  }
  else $('<li/>').text(value).appendTo(el);
 });
}

// this JSON matches better with your desired output image
// it appears that integration and gateways are "collapsed"
// which would be a simple styling application. If they
// are in fact empty, you could just remove the children items
// from the JSON.
var newData = [  
    {  
       "For Home Products":[  
          "Small Business",
          "Managed Services",
          "Internet Security"
       ]
    },
    {  
       "For Business Products":[  
          {  
             "Client/Servers":[  
                "Professional Security",
                "Server Security"
             ]
          },
          {  
             "Integration":[  
                "Anti-Malware",
                "Antispam SDK (SPACE)",
                "Rebranding &amp; Bundling",
                "Integration Services"
             ]
          },
          "Small Business",
          "Managed Services",
          {  
             "Gateways":[  
                "Menu MailGate",
                "Menu MailGate Suite",
                "Menu AntiVir Exchange",
                "Menu WebGate",
                "Menu WebGate Suite",
                "Menu GateWay Bundle",
                "Menu SharePoint"
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
 ];

setData(newData, $('body'));

// Original JSON which doesn't match desired output
/*
var data = [  
    {  
       "For Home Products":[  
          "Menu Free Antivirus",
          "Menu Premium",
          "Menu Internet Security"
       ]
    },
    {  
       "For Business Products":[  
          {  
             "Client/Servers":[  
                "Menu Professional Security",
                "Menu Server Security",
                "Menu Business Security Suite",
                "Menu Endpoint Security"
             ]
          },
          {  
             "Integration":[  
                "Anti-Malware",
                "Antispam SDK (SPACE)",
                "Rebranding &amp; Bundling",
                "Integration Services"
             ]
          },
          "Small Business",
          "Managed Services",
          {  
             "Gateways":[  
                "Menu MailGate",
                "Menu MailGate Suite",
                "Menu AntiVir Exchange",
                "Menu WebGate",
                "Menu WebGate Suite",
                "Menu GateWay Bundle",
                "Menu SharePoint"
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
 ];

setData(data, $('body'));
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for your time. The problem is, that that's not the output. See the picture provided above for the expected output.

Comment: @Cristian what exactly is your objection? That I didn't apply the CSS styling with the dot and folder images? Or that I didn't remove the word "Menu " from the JSON items? I wasn't trying to write a finished product for you, I was just trying to help you get the code to make the _structure._

Comment: i thought the same way as you in the first time. That the output should be that one. Look at the picture and you will notice that that's not the output. Thank you again :)

The structure is different

Comment: There has to be a logical relationship between your JSON and the data structure you hope to achieve. In your JSON, under the `Home` category you have `Antivirus`, `Premium` and `Internet Sec`. In your "desired output," you have `Small Bus`, `Managed Svc` and `Internet Sec`. But in the JSON, `Small Bus` and `Managed Svc` appear down under the `Business Products` category. Is it possible you've got a bad JSON, maybe a JSON from another project or from an older version or something?

Comment: I've modified the JSON in my answer to give results more in line with your desired output. Please see notes in comment above JSON regarding the `Integration` and `Gateways` sections, which appear to be collapsed.

Comment: I've thought of that too. I think I need to create another object with the data from that JSON and make it like the desired output and this is what I'm doing.

Comment: Damn, this is the worst JSON or any set of data that I have ever worked with!! It gets me nuts!!!

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that the levels of your json aren't uniform, so at times you're returning the name you want, and at other times that level is an object, so you're returning the object. You'll need to check for that in your code with something like this:

```
$.each(value2, function(key3, value3) {
    // console.log(value3);
    if(typeof value3 !== 'object') {
        var z = document.createElement("li");
        z.setAttribute("id", value3);
        z.innerHTML = value3;
        document.getElementById(key2).appendChild(z);
        console.log(value3);
    } else {
        // Go a level deeper in your json.
    }
});
```

All I did was add the following check in:

```
if(typeof value3 !== 'object') {
    // If not object.
} else {
    // If object.
}
```

What the addition above does is check the type of the value3 variable and if it isn't an object, it'll create the li, otherwise you know it is an you can handle it appropriately.

Comment: I'd love some feedback from the downvote so I can consider how I can improve. Thanks.