# How to transform from weird Json to simpler Object or Array

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a json that comes like this:

```
var data = [
    {
        "For Home Products": [
            "Menu Free Antivirus",
            "Menu Premium",
            "Menu Internet Security"
        ]
    },
    {
        "For Business Products": [
            {
                "Client/Servers": [
                    "Menu Professional Security",
                    "Menu Server Security",
                    "Menu Business Security Suite",
                    "Menu Endpoint Security"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Integration": [
                    "Anti-Malware",
                    "Antispam SDK (SPACE)",
                    "Rebranding &amp; Bundling",
                    "Integration Services"
                ]
            },
            "Small Business",
            "Managed Services",
            {
                "Gateways": [
                    "Menu MailGate",
                    "Menu MailGate Suite",
                    "Menu AntiVir Exchange",
                    "Menu WebGate",
                    "Menu WebGate Suite",
                    "Menu GateWay Bundle",
                    "Menu SharePoint"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My question is, how do I transform this into an easier to work object? I mean to have another object named "newData" for example. I'm trying for two days now to work with this data and I just can't and I'm missing something in trying to make it easier. I hope you guys are understanding what I'm meaning, I know I'm not a good explainer. Thank you in advance for this!!

My output should be this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO6k5.png

Later edit: this question is different than the first question I’ve asked because I have identified the issue I was having there and that’s the structure of the JSON and the different structure of the Output. My question now, is how do I transform this into simpler object or array to work with.

Comment: This is already a JS object. What exactly do you want to achieve? Get a JS object from JSON?

Comment: @Orlandster if you notice the output, it's different from the way that the JSON is constructed. I want to create a new object that will be in the way that the output should be without changing the JSON or hard coding it. Hope that I was more explicit this time

Comment: Is that array always length two?

Comment: @Ele yes, the structure of the JSON won't change

Comment: Why have you duplicated your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49203952/i-have-a-small-issue-with-json)?

Comment: @Amy i consider this being a different question since the problem changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `reduce` to transform into an easier object for manipulating data.

*This approach returns a `key-value` object.*

```js
var data = [    {        "For Home Products": [            "Menu Free Antivirus",            "Menu Premium",            "Menu Internet Security"        ]    },    {        "For Business Products": [            {                "Client/Servers": [                    "Menu Professional Security",                    "Menu Server Security",                    "Menu Business Security Suite",                    "Menu Endpoint Security"                ]            },            {                "Integration": [                    "Anti-Malware",                    "Antispam SDK (SPACE)",                    "Rebranding &amp; Bundling",                    "Integration Services"                ]            },            "Small Business",            "Managed Services",            {                "Gateways": [                    "Menu MailGate",                    "Menu MailGate Suite",                    "Menu AntiVir Exchange",                    "Menu WebGate",                    "Menu WebGate Suite",                    "Menu GateWay Bundle",                    "Menu SharePoint"                ]            }        ]    }],
    [forPro, forBus] = data;

var forProKey = Object.keys(forPro).pop();
var forbusKey = Object.keys(forBus).pop();

// The function 'reduce' is only to further properties in the future.
var newObject = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (c[forProKey]) a[forProKey] = c[forProKey];
  else a[forbusKey] = c[forbusKey];
  
  return a;
}, {[forProKey]: [], [forbusKey]: []});

console.log(newObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Analysis

Converting `data` to a menu written as

```
{"main menu": data}
```

shows the input structure of a menu object to be:

```
{"menu label": menuItemsArray}
```

where

- the label of a menu object is the name of its single own property. Labels may be used to labels folders/books/collections/expanders as required.
- the value of the menu object's label property is an array of menu items.
- menu items are either leaf nodes, of type string, or non leaf nodes whose type and structure is that of a menu object. In short a submenu node.

#### Design

A more useful data structure could use two kinds of objects:

1. A menu or submenu object:

   ```
   {   isMenu: true,   // a menu or submenu item
       label:  menuLabelText,
       items:  arrayOfMenuItems
   }
   ```
2. A leaf node object (text only)

   ```
   {   isMenu: false,  // a leaf node
       value:  text
   }
   ```

#### Coding

This is concept code to produce an intermediary form of the data to work with:

```js
function convertData( menuData) {
    if( !menuData || typeof menuData !="object") {
        throw new TypeError("invalid convertData argument");
    }
    var keys = Object.keys( menuData);
    if( keys.length != 1) {
         throw new TypeError("invalid menu or submenu object");
    }
    var label = keys[0];
    var itemData = menuData[label];
    var node = { isMenu: true, label: label, items: []};

    itemData.forEach( function (item) {
        if( typeof item == "string") {
            node.items.push( {isMenu: false, value: item});
        }
        else if( item && (typeof item == "object") ){
            node.items.push( convertData( item));
        }
        else {
            throw new TypeError("invalid menu item: string or object expected")
        }
    });
    return node;
}

//___________________________________________________
//  and test

var data = [
    {
        "For Home Products": [
            "Menu Free Antivirus",
            "Menu Premium",
            "Menu Internet Security"
        ]
    },
    {
        "For Business Products": [
            {
                "Client/Servers": [
                    "Menu Professional Security",
                    "Menu Server Security",
                    "Menu Business Security Suite",
                    "Menu Endpoint Security"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Integration": [
                    "Anti-Malware",
                    "Antispam SDK (SPACE)",
                    "Rebranding &amp; Bundling",
                    "Integration Services"
                ]
            },
            "Small Business",
            "Managed Services",
            {
                "Gateways": [
                    "Menu MailGate",
                    "Menu MailGate Suite",
                    "Menu AntiVir Exchange",
                    "Menu WebGate",
                    "Menu WebGate Suite",
                    "Menu GateWay Bundle",
                    "Menu SharePoint"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

var newData = convertData( {main: data});
console.log( newData)
```

#### Testing

I made the code runnable to see if it did what I expected. I had to debug it a little before it worked.

#### Documentation

`convertData` is called as `convertData( {anyPropertyName: data})` and returns a menu object, not an array.